# Magento Error log record number: 508673659403

Tags: zend-framework, magento-1.6

I have just installed Magento 1.9.0.1 and i am getting the below error Any Help?

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 508673659403

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue was with my browser cache. I switched to a different browser and it worked. You can also clear your browser cache and use the same browser.